# Gaussian fit to plot, plotted using bar(x,y)

Tags: matlab, histogram, gaussian, normal-distribution, bar-chart

I have plotted a normal distribution from a set of data, x and y, using `bar(x,y)`, and I know  it's a normal distribution.

Now, I want to:

1. Plot the normal distribution curve (or Gaussian), fitted to the bar-plot, in the figure.
2. Get the equation, so that I can calculate the maximum point and the width at half maximum.

I have been looking at `histfit` but it doesn't really work for me (just like `hist` didn't work for plotting the data, as I already know both x and y, I think?). Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why `histfit` doesn't work for you?

Comment: Probably because I don't know how to use it, even though I have read the description. My data is kinda like x=1, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, and y is the counts of each value of x, so e.g. y=0, 2, 6, 2, 0

Comment: `histfit()` works on raw data, but you already have it binned. Do you have original data?

Comment: My data is from an experiment, which I know yields a normal distribution. I know both the x and y values.

Answer (score 0):

A trick, which however does **NOT** recover the original raw data (therefore the fit suffers also from the approximations introduced by the binning), is to decode with the run-length algorithm your `x`, and run `histfit()` on that data:

```
% data from your previous question
x = [0 0.0278 0.0556 0.0833 0.1111 0.1389 0.1667 0.1945 0.2222];
y = [1 3 10 13 28 53 66 91 137];

% histfit 
histfit(rude(y,x),9,'normal')
```

where you can find the run-length encoding/decoding function on [FEX: `rude()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6436-rude-a-pedestrian-run-length-decoder-encoder).

The result:

[image]